# How to use nativeGL(C++) function except for native function(JNI) in GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

**[Edit1]**

In my android application, I have used native(C++) GL functions only in my own GLSurfaceView.Renderer. I have used native GL functions, glUniform4f()/glEnableVertexAttribArray()/glBindBuffer()... like the second code block I posted, at the native functions in the SCRendere class

Now, I need to use (native) GL functions not in GLSurfaceView.Renderer.

This is the java code of GLSurfaceView.Renderer

```
class SCRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        nativeInit();
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    nativeResize(w, h);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        nativeRender(mSurfaceViewID);
    }

    private static native void nativeInit();
    private static native void nativeResize(int w, int h);
    private static native void nativeRender(int rendererID);

    public int mSurfaceViewID;
}
```

This is the usecase of native GL functions without any problem

```
JNIEXPORT void
Java_com_samsung_smartcampus_SCRenderer_nativeRender(JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz, jint surfaceViewID )
{
    appRender(sWindowWidth, sWindowHeight, surfaceViewID);

}


void appRender(int width, int height, int rendererID)
{
    ....
    for (int iIdx = 0; iIdx < pRENDER_PARAMS[0].numObjects; ++iIdx) {
        glUniform4f(colorLoc,
                    pMeshContext[iIdx].vColor.x,
                    pMeshContext[iIdx].vColor.y,
                    pMeshContext[iIdx].vColor.z,
                    1.0f);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)positionLoc);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pMeshContext[iIdx].vertexID);
        glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)positionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)normalLoc);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pMeshContext[iIdx].normalID);
        glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)normalLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0 , (GLsizei)pMeshContext[iIdx].numVertices);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)positionLoc);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)normalLoc);
    }
    ....
```

What I want to implement is that when I open the file at other class in java, I need to use native GL in the class. Currently I have stuck because I think that probably there is no GL context in the other class(file open class).

This is the file open java class.

```
class FileLoader{
    ...
    private void loadSTL(String paths){
        nativeloadSTL(paths);
    }
    ...

    private static native void nativeloadSTL(String paths);
    ...
}
```

And this is the native C++ part.

```
void SCFileLoader::loadSTL(const char* path){
    ...
        loader->changeFileSTLtoMeshData(iCnt);
        glGenBuffers(1, &pMeshContext[iCnt].vertexID);
        glGenBuffers(1, &pMeshContext[iCnt].normalID);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pMeshContext[iCnt].vertexID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pMeshContext[iCnt].numVertices*3*sizeof(GLfloat),
                     pMeshContext[iCnt].vertexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pMeshContext[iCnt].normalID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pMeshContext[iCnt].numVertices*3*sizeof(GLfloat),
                     pMeshContext[iCnt].vertexNormals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ...
}
```

As I did like just above the code block, GL functions doesn't work. I guess this is because there is no GL context.

Is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: The question is not so clear, so I guess that you want to use gl instructions in a class which is not extended from GLSurfaceView. As far as I know, if you want to use these instructions, you need to be in the GLThread, so, If you make a different class with gl functions, you need to execute in your GLSurface view extended class. What have you tried?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to use the native functions? What is the scope of your other class?

Comment: Thanks @Harish for the answer. I am implementing the android application with jni. What I have done is that I have several java class, for example file open class/rendering class and so on. I have no problem until I need to use native GL function like glgenBuffers()/glBindBuffer/glBufferData at the file open class. Because so far I used native GL functions in the renderer class I have shown above.